# Send request from browser from HTTPS to HTTP, mixed content

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, mixed-content

I'm trying to make a fetch to my API hosted locally from my GitHub page, but I can't due to the mixed content error. Is there a way to get around it? I'm not sending sensitive information or whatever and I don't need a response.

Comment: You can run your local service over HTTPS. If you need help with that, please provide details

Comment: I'm using a raspberry pi 3 running python flask, I've tried Let's Encrypt but I could not find an appropriate tutorial to make it run. And I would rather not run it over NGINX, Apache or other things like that.

Comment: I would honestly just use NGINX as a terminating proxy ~ https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either use HTTPS or HTTP across the board.  You can't use half one and half the other.

> I'm not sending sensitive information or whatever

HTTPS is not just about the encryption of the information, but also to ensure that you're connected to an authorized server.  There are *many* ways connections get hijacked... including broken public WiFi access points with captive portals.  In any case, the browser vendors don't give us much of a choice these days.